# Git ignores all files

Tags: django, git, gitignore

My gitignore file looks straighforward:

```
env/
.idea
*.pyc
__pycache__
*.env
/environment
db.sqlite3
*.log
```

When I do `git add .` from my root project folder and then check status - I see there is no files tracked.
When I do `git status --ignored`, I see that all folders are ignored:

```
.flake8
.gitignore
.idea/
 Procfile
 env/
 requirements.txt
 runtime.txt
 src/
```

So it somehow ignores all the folders and files.
I tried to comment everything in `gitignore` - and the result is the same.

I tried to reinitialize the git by:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

And the result is the same.

How can I add my files, without `git add --force`?
I want files that are added in `gitignore` to be ignored, but still to commit other files.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What is the output of `git check-ignore -v`?

Comment: I bet these are not *ignored* but rather *untracked*.

Comment: @eftshift0, output is: fatal: no path specified

Comment: @torek why are they untracked after git add . command?

Comment: That's a good question: is it possible the `git add` itself is being run from the wrong directory? Let's augment @eftshift0's question with `git check-ignore -v requirements.txt` for instance, though.

Comment: @torek, I run git add from the root project folder. the output is the following: /Users/admin/.gitignore:2:*     requirements.txt

Comment: Aha, that's the answer then: you have a *global* `.gitignore` that lists `*`, for some reason, in `/Users/admin/.gitignore`.

Comment: @torek what can I do with that?

Comment: Find out why you have this global `.gitignore`. You could just remove it, but presumably you have it for some reason. What's the reason?

Comment: @torek I don't know :) maybe it was created by macOS ?

Comment: macOS wouldn't do that (mine never did, although I'm a release behind). Listing `*` in a global `.gitignore` seems wrong, but *someone* did it for *some* reason. Who, and why?

Comment: @torek, I don't know. 
I see this at the top of the file: # created by virtualenv automatically

Comment: OK, so you ran `virtualenv` or used the `venv` package (new in Python 3.3) to create a Python virtual environment, including that `.gitignore`; or you ran something that ran those. That still seems like a bad idea, but now you have a chance to track down anything that might depend on it. (The kind of thing that belongs in your personal global `.gitignore` are the patterns for editor temporary files, such as vim's `*.swp` or Emacs's `*~`.) It seems odd that you're logged in as `admin`, too: normally on macOS you should create a user account and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments: it seems that `venv` or `virtualenv` created a global `.gitignore` (in `/Users/admin/.gitignore`) whose second line read `*`, ignoring all files.

It's not clear what caused this venv entry to be created in `/Users/admin` in the first place, so finding out if anything depends on it remains to be done, but in the meantime, any virtual environment data in the home directory here should be moved or removed, so that the global `.gitignore` isn't there any more.